# I can't get number of inversions using java in merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm designing  `A[0..n − 1]` be an array of n real numbers.

A pair (A[i], A[j ]) is said to be an inversion if these numbers are out of order, i.e., **i < j but A[i]>A[j]**. `O(n log n)` algorithm for counting the number of inversions.

I'm trying to get the number of inversions but i didn't know what is the problem with my code , i think there is a problem in sort method .

```
    class Q2
    { 
// Merges two subarrays of arr[]. 
// First subarray is arr[l..m] 
// Second subarray is arr[m+1..r] 
         static int merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) 
    { 
    // Find sizes of two subarrays to be merged 
    int n1 = m - l + 1; 
    int n2 = r - m; 
    int counter =0;

    /* Create temp arrays */
    int L[] = new int [n1]; 
    int R[] = new int [n2]; 

    /*Copy data to temp arrays*/
    for (int i=0; i<n1; ++i) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (int j=0; j<n2; ++j) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j]; 


    /* Merge the temp arrays */

    // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays 
    int i = 0, j = 0; 

    // Initial index of merged subarry array 
    int k = l; 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
    { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
        { 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 

            i++; 
        } 
        else
        { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
            counter = counter + (m - i); 
        } 
        k++; 

    } 

    /* Copy remaining elements of L[] if any */
    while (i < n1) 
    { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 

    /* Copy remaining elements of R[] if any */
    while (j < n2) 
    { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
    return counter ;
    } 

// Main function that sorts arr[l..r] using 
// merge() 
    static int sort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
   { 
    int counter=0;
    if (l < r) 
    { 
        // Find the middle point 
        int m = (l+r)/2; 

        // count first and second halves
      counter=sort(arr, l, m); 
       counter+=sort(arr , m+1, r); 

        // count two halves
       counter+= merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
    return counter;
    } 



// Driver method 
     public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 1, 3,5}; 





    System.out.println("Number of inversions are " + sort(arr, 0,arr.length-1 ) ); 

      } 
      }
```

Comment: What *is* the problem with your code? Do you get an error? Not the correct output?

Comment: Please tab code correctly before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace

```
 counter = counter + (m - i)
```

with

```
 counter = counter + (n1 - i)
```

Illustration: Suppose a left array L with numbers 1, 6, 8, 9 and a right array R with numbers 4, 5, 7. The following shows the iterations through the loop for a single recursion step:

[image]

Generally you can sort the array by performing the inversions in different order. However, the **minimum** number of inversions needed for sorting is unambiguous and thus independent of that order. Since the algorithm uses one of those alternative sequences it provides the unambiguous minimum number of inversions. That means in particular no inversion is counted twice or omitted.

The algorithm provides for your array {2, 4, 1, 3, 5} a minimum number of 3 inversions in total: (4, 1), (4, 3) and (2,1).

Answer (score 0):

There is one fundamental flaw in your method. The

```
counter = counter + (m - i)
```

assumes that all elements before m are smaller than the value in R, which is not correct. Remember that a large part of the array before m may already be sorted.

```
counter = counter + (m - l - i)
```

may be more correct, but you are probably still counting double in that case as well. Note that you count them when they are not in there original place in the original array.